# Resistors, what do I need for my 3V LEDS?

Tags: led, batteries, resistors

I bought some lights off of Amazon in both the "White" and "Warm white" options ([Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P8PMCCS)).

I think they are 3 V and operate at 15 mA, whatever that means. I want to wire the lights in a series/parallel circuit.

Key:

- Red: Positive
- Yellow: Negative / Ground
- Blue: Resistor (Green numbers are for ohms - See below)
- Green: Switch
- Grey: Lights with back numbers (Lights #3&4 are "White" and Lights 1,2,5,6,7 are "Warm White").
- Purple: 9 V battery

[image: My Circuit]

The problem:
Only some lights will light up. Some only partially light up, etc. (Note: this is when I had fewer resistors in weird spots, not relevant anymore)

The solution:
Add a resistor (Blue in diagram)

Where I get stuck:
What resistors do I need?

The resistors that come with the lights (Labeled "5.1V-9V use") power one just fine (Like #5), but don't power the pairs well (Every light but #5).

I think I need a 200 Ω (or maybe 180 Ω) resistor on the dual pair. And 390 Ω or 100 Ω on the single one. But I honestly have no clue, and each person I ask says something different.

The ones I'm using now for the lights that work are, I believe, 100 MΩ, but that makes no sense.

[image: Resistor]

Also, I have no clue what side goes first...

[image: Maybe this one?]

[image: Or this one]

Can anyone help me figure out what resistor (and 5-band color) would be needed for both the 1 and 2 light combinations?

I am not sure if the ones that came with the lights are the best or not.

Thanks!

I'm also brand new at this, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: It looks like you have already asked this question and gotten answers. If you have new information you should edit the existing question rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Try looking at that resistor upside down: it may be a 160 ohm resistor

Comment: You do realize that LEDs are polarized? They have a plus and minus pin. If you connected them backwards at some point you may have damaged them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We like schematic diagrams here. If you plan on doing more electronics, try to become familiar:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvw2QJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Both **cool white** and **warm white** are similar - the only difference is the phosphor coating the underlying blue LED. So both types drop a similar 3 volts.

For the single LED (D5), the resistor must make up the difference (9V - 3V)=6V. With 15mA flowing through both resistor and LED, the resistor should be 6V/0.015 ohms. That's 400 ohms. Nearest standard value is 390 ohms. You're using 1% resistors? That's OK, find one near 400 ohms.

For the two-diode string, both LEDS in series take 6V of the 9V battery. That leaves 3V for the resistor....3V/0.015 gives 200 ohms. Use a resistor near this value - a smaller resistor gives **more current**, and those two LEDS will be a bit brighter.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the diagram, didn't even see the button to add one (I found it now). That makes sense, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the future it would help to make a circuit diagram, this is what I see from what your diagram shows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Q5RZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED being 3V and 15mA sounds correct, that's typical. It means you will want to choose a resistor that ensures there is 3 volts across the LED when it's consuming 15mA, this prevents it from drawing too much power and burning out.

You have 3 pairs of LEDs in series, and one alone. That means the resistor in the series combo needs to drop (9 - (2*3)) = 3 volts, and the resistor on the lone LED needs to drop (9 - 3) = 6 volts. Current is continuous through a wire, so 15mA is the current.

Using those values, you use Ohm's law which is very basic. This will calculate the values for the resistor:

V = IR -> R = V/I

(series)

R = 3/(15e-3) = **200 Ohms**, 220 is common

(lone)

R = 6/(15e-3) = **400 Ohms**, the 360 will be fine. That resistor you posted a picture of is definitely not 100M, its probably 360.

Resistors are non-polar, so you can connect them either way. LEDs have a pretty large operating range, so you can choose whichever reading is the closest.

Comment: Thanks for the Anwer, will make sure to add the schematic next time. Makes a lot more sense now.